# Stochastic volatility model- autocorrelation of $\Delta \ln(y_t^2)$

Tags: time-series, self-study, autocorrelation

for the following stochastic volatility model : $y_t = exp(\frac{\alpha_t}{2}) \epsilon_t $
where $\epsilon_t \sim NID(0,1) $
$\alpha_{t+1} = \phi \alpha_t + (1-\phi)\mu +\eta_t$
where $\eta_t\sim NID(0,\sigma_n^2)$
setting $\phi =1$       i.e $\Delta \alpha_{t+1} = \eta_t$
prove that  the autocorrelation coefficient of $\Delta \ln(y_t^2)$ at lag 1 is $$-\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}{\pi^2+\sigma_n^2}$$

I know that $\ln(y_t^2) = \alpha_t+\ln(\epsilon_t^2)$

$\ln(\epsilon_t^2)\sim WN(-1.27,\frac{\pi^2}{2})$

I have a hard time proving this result

I got for $Var(\Delta \ln(y_t^2) = \frac{2 \sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2}(1-\phi)+\pi^2$

$$Var(\Delta \ln(y_t^2)) = E(\alpha_t+\ln(\epsilon_t^2)-\alpha_{t-1}-\ln(\epsilon_{t-1}^2))^2 = 
\frac{2\sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2} + \frac{\pi^2}{2}-\frac{2 \phi \sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2}+ \frac{\pi^2}{2} = \frac{2 \sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2}(1-\phi)+\pi^2$$
we know that $\alpha_t$ is an AR(1) process with mean $E(\alpha_t) = \mu$ $Var(\alpha_t) = \frac{\sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2}$ and $Cov(\alpha_t,\alpha_{t-j}) = \phi^j \frac{\sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2}$

for the autovariance at lag 1 I got $\gamma(1) = -\frac{\sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2} (1-\phi)^2-\frac{\pi}{2}$

at then end the autocorrelation at lag 1 $$\rho(1) = \frac{\gamma(1)}{\gamma(0)} = -\frac{\frac{\sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2}(1-\phi)^2-\frac{\pi^2}{2}}{\frac{2\sigma_n^2}{1-\phi^2}(1-\phi)+\pi^2}$$

can someone help me to get the correct result?

Comment: Let the following hold. VAR denotes vector autoregression. VaR denotes value at risk. Var denotes variance. I suppose by VAR you mean Var?

Comment: yes, I mean variance

Comment: where did the $\pi$ come from ?

Comment: have a look to my edits $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$ is the variance of $\ln(\epsilon_t^2)$